# Difference between viewmodelfactory and view model injection using activity module

Tags: java, android, kotlin, androidx, android-mvvm

I am wondering which one of below two approaches better suit my android application and the reasons for it.

First is using **viewmodelfactory pattern** and second is **viewModelStoreProvider**. Can anyone shed some light on these approaches?

**First Approach:**

```
@Singleton
class BaseViewModelFactory<T>(val creator: () -> T) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        return creator() as T
    }

2.ViewModelStoreOwner code :
class ViewModelStoreProvider
    constructor(viewModelProvider: ViewModelStoreOwner) {

    var viewModelStore: ViewModelStoreOwner = viewModelProvider

    inline fun <reified T : ViewModel> getViewModel(noinline creator: (() -> T)? = null): T {
        return if (creator == null)
            ViewModelProvider(viewModelStore).get(T::class.java)
        else
            ViewModelProvider(viewModelStore, BaseViewModelFactory(creator)).get(T::class.java)
    }
}
```

And creating instance of view model using below code anywhere in app (Application, activity, fragment)

```
viewModelStoreProvider.getViewModel { ConfigViewModel(firebaseRemoteConfigRepository)}
```

**Second Approach:**

BaseViewModel class :

```
open class BaseViewModel<N>(
    val dataManager: DataManager,
    val schedulerProvider: SchedulerProvider
) : ViewModel() {
    open var navigator: N? = null
    val compositeDisposable: CompositeDisposable

    init {
        this.compositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()
    }

    override fun onCleared() {
        compositeDisposable.dispose()
        super.onCleared()
    }
}

class LoginViewModel(dataManager: DataManager, schedulerProvider: SchedulerProvider) :
    BaseViewModel<LoginNavigator>(dataManager, schedulerProvider) {

    override var navigator: LoginNavigator?
        get() = super.navigator
        set(navigator) {
            super.navigator = navigator
        }

    public override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
    }
}

@Module
class LoginActivityModule {
    @Provides
    internal fun provideLoginViewModel(
        dataManager: DataManager,
        schedulerProvider: SchedulerProvider
    ): LoginViewModel {
        return LoginViewModel(dataManager, schedulerProvider)
    }
}
```

And we are injecting view model in Activity using

```
@Inject
override lateinit var viewModel: LoginViewModel
    internal set
```

Please let me know if anything is unclear and I will do my best to answer it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ViewModelFactory` is the right way to create `ViewModels` with constructor parameters. It will take care of everything related to ViewModel according to its parent `Activity/Fragment` Lifecycle.

For example, it will keep the same instance during configuration changes, it will call `onCleared` automatically when activity is destroyed.

With injection approach, you will be responsible for everything related to the lifecycle of `ViewModel`, like when to create a new instance, how/when `onCleared` will be called.